# Moving Xcode Projects to different computer

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I got a new computer and downloaded Xcode and transferred all my old projects to it. What all do I need to do with keychain to submit apps from new computer, or do I just need to transfer the provisioning profiles from old computer as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export your profile from the "Devices" organizer. Click on your team name, then on export (at the bottom). You can then set a password that you'll need to import the profile on the new computer. It should contain all provisioning profiles, certificates and private keys that you need.

Here's the relevant documentation page: [Exporting Your Code Signing Assets to Your File System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/export_signing_assets.html)

Comment: What happens if I had already deleted XCode off the original computer.  Could I just reinstall it and still do the same thing?

Comment: Probably yes, this stuff isn't stored in the Xcode app itself.

Comment: The link generates a 404

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's quite straight-forward.

You will indeed need to transfer your Developer Certificates over.

To do this, use the Keychain Access tool, click on 'My Certificates', find your iPhone Developer certificate, select it, and then use 'Export Items...' in the file menu to export.

Then, transfer the exported certificates to your new machine.  You can then just double-click on the files on the new machine to automagically add them to your local keychain.

You can also use Xcode Organiser (on your new machine) to sync your provisions with your iOS developer account.

Xcode projects are themselves totally self-contained. So bundle (zip, or whatever) it up and transfer it over, and unzip.

It should then all just work.

It's a good idea to use GIT or Subversion to hold your Xcode projects if you're going to use multiple machines to develop the same project.  I do this and it works very well.

Good luck!

Comment: I did this and it turnes out that my imported frameworks and project config (e.g. URL Types) are NOT being transferred. For some reason these settings are saved elsewhere.